# Unable to use "User Mode Debugger" in VS2013 on VirtualBox machine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, wdf

Trying to configure Visual Studio 2013 (pro, FWIW) to debug a VirtualBox host. I followed [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj200334%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set up the host correctly: It works for kernel mode, but not for user mode. Here is the debugger settings:

[image: Visual Studio Computer configuration of VirtualBox host]

When I use kernel mode it works (and I'm debugging the kernel successfully):

[image: Transport and Qualifier: Kernel Mode]

But I cannot do it for user mode. I ran:

```
dbgsrv.exe -t tcp:port=53902
```

and saw that `dbgsrv.exe` actually runs, but still I get this:

[image: Transport and Qualifier: User Mode]

Actually it makes sense, since I never specified the machine name/IP (where should I enter it?).

The firewall is off and the machine is accessible via network (files sharing).

So how to accomplish user-mode-debugging (`Windows User Mode Debugger`, not `Remote`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, silly me... the "Computer name" must match the VirtualBox host name...